# Connection Pool configuration: Tomcat jndi, SSL and MySQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: mysql, ssl, tomcat7, jndi, connection-pooling

I'm using the tomcat connection pool via JNDI resources.

To avoid that the connection is lost after a long inactivity (more of 8 hours, that is the default value of MySQL variable `wait_timeout`), I have put `validationQuery` and  `testOnBorrow` in the `context.xml`.

My `context.xml` is:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          maxActive="30" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
          username="myuser" password="mypwd" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" closeMethod="close" 
          validationQuery="select 1" testOnBorrow="true" />
```

It works, but if a I use a SSL connection, it doesn't work anymore.

I obtain:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No 
 operations allowed after connection closed.
 ...
 Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet 
 successfully received from the server was 328,606,914 milliseconds ago.  The last 
 packet sent successfully to the server was 328,606,914 milliseconds ago. is longer 
 than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either 
 expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, 
 increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the 
 Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

I wouldn't to use `autoreconnect=true`, 'cause it is not recommended by [MySQL team itself](http://pages.citebite.com/p4x3a0r8pmhm)

What could be the issue? Why this difference between SSL and no-SSL?

**EDIT**

It seems to work by putting ssl=true in the query string of the connection to db:

```
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;ssl=true"
```